# can't Set Path for Custom Object

Tags: salespath

I have created a new custom Object and when i try to create a path for this Object using Path Setting.I can't find this Object.

the place where i put the Path
[image: the place where i put the Path]

in the List of Object i can't find my new custom Object but i can find all old custom Object
[image: in the List of Object i can't find my new custom Object but i can find all old custom Object]

Comment: Does your Custom Object have a Record Type, a picklist field, and a Sales Process defined? You need those things to create a Path.

Comment: @DavidReed only partly true: you don't need to have a Record Type on a custom object. And  Sales Processes are only available for Opportunity - not Custom Objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have permissions to the object and to the picklist field you want to set up the path for. If you can't see the object in the list you most likely do not have permissions to that object. Adjust permission set or profile accordingly.

Also:
Without the permissions for e.g. the correct picklist field you get record type errors.